# parsley.js custom validator - not equal to

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

Hi I'm using parsleyjs for my form validation.

http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html

I want a custom validator so that an input value can not equal what I specify...

An example using jQuery validation can be seen here... [How to add a Not Equal To rule in jQuery.validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571347/how-to-add-a-not-equal-to-rule-in-jquery-validation)

I'm thinking something like..

```
$( '#form' ).parsley( {
    validators: {
      notEqual: function ( val, ??? ) {
        return val != ??? ;
      }
    }
  , messages: {
      notEqual: "Please enter a valid value"
    }
} );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me. You also have to set `data-notEqual="#element"`.

```
validators: {
    notEqual: function ( val, elem ) {
        return val !== $( elem ).val();
    }
},
messages: {
    notEqual: "This value should not be the same."
},
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!