# Parsley Not Equal Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have change password screen
and i want Current Password and New Password should not be same
is there a way to do this using parsley

i also try with following condition but get no luck.

```
data_parsley_notequalto = "#controlId"
```

Comment: You would need to write a custom validator - have a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361050/parsley-js-custom-validator-not-equal-to

Answer (score 4):

This code worked well for me in many cases:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator("notequalto", {
    requirementType: "string",
    validateString: function(value, element) {
        return value !== $(element).val();
    }
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="test1" data-parsley-required>
<input type="text" id="test2" data-parsley-required data-parsley-notequalto="#test1" data-parsley-notequalto-message="These two fields must not be identical!">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you.

Then I found out you can create a custom validator.

Here's mine:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" data-parsley-notequalto="test" />
```

Add this before including `parsley.js`

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
  validators: {
    notequalto: {
      fn: function (value, id) {
        return value !== $('#id').val();
      },
      priority: 32
    }
  },
  i18n: {
    en: {
      notequalto: 'This value not equal to %s'
    }
  }
};
```

This will check if the value of `#myInput` is equal to `'test'`. If equal it will display the error message specified.