# Dropdown validation does not work

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

it's my validation for [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) enabled select:

```
SellerDropDownList: {
    required: {
        depends: function (element) {
            return $("#SellerDropDownList").val() == "-1";
        }
    }
}
```

Default value is `-1`, but it does not work and when I click submit button; It passes validation while chosen selected value is `-1`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/rLQDK/18/

Comment: I tested two things: [Chosen does not matter here](http://jsfiddle.net/rLQDK/19/). And your `depends` function never runs.

Comment: So how should I fix it?

Comment: I don't know yet. I will try reading the documentation, never used this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation, [`required`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method) does not work the way you are trying to use it.

One option I found to work is `min`:

```
    SellerDropDownList: {
        min: 0
    },
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLQDK/20/)

Another possible way is to define your own rule ("not equal") described under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571347/how-to-add-a-not-equal-to-rule-in-jquery-validation).

Comment: It only works when the plugin is not applied. http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/rLQDK/25/ does not work.

Comment: @Maysam See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232310/how-can-i-use-jquery-validation-with-the-chosen-plugin

Comment: I have multiple chosens; "not equal" does not work too.

Comment: @Maysam See the second answer, that will enable hidden selects to be validated: http://jsfiddle.net/rLQDK/31/