# jquery form validate equal

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

hello i have case in my jquery, ex :

i have drop-down list and text field form :

```
<select id="id_level"  name="id_level">
<option value=""  > -choose-</option>
<option value="1"  > -Administrator-</option>
<option value="2"  > -Kondektur Bus-</option>
<option value="3"  > -Staf Operasi-</option>
</select>

<input name="job" type="text" id="job"/>
```

i want validate  drop-down list with:
**required** : "must choose"
and **equal** with :

```
var text_id_level = $("#id_level option:selected" ).text();
    var val_job= $("job").val();

    if(text_id_level !=""){

            if(text_id_level =="Administrator" && (val_job!="Kondektur Bus" || val_job!="Staf Operasi"))
            {
                // equal = true
            }

            else if(text_id_level == val_job) 
            {
                // equal = true
            }

            else
            {
                // equal = false , message : not equal
            }

    }

    else
    {
        // equal = false, message : must choose
    }
```

how to format code above in jquery validate plugin ? 
format like

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, "Please specify a different (non-default) value");
```

from here >> [How to add a Not Equal To rule in jQuery.validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571347/how-to-add-a-not-equal-to-rule-in-jquery-validation)

and this my jquery validate metode

```
$("#Form").validate({
        rules: {
            id_level:"required",
                        job:"required",

        },
        messages: {
            id_level:"choose one",
                        job:"must fill"
        }
    });
```

and i don't know how equals metode for my case, sorry for my english

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).  Then make an honest attempt at solving your own problem; don't just expect us to do it for you.

Comment: i have read and i have get stack ... so i ask here ... thanks

Comment: If that's true, then show us where and how you're stuck.  What exactly have you done so far?  Where is your call to `.validate()`?  What options did you try?  What error messages did you get?  In other words, you need to ask a very specific question... not just _"I got stuck so do all the work for me."_

Comment: i'm sorry, this is mistake,  can't you look again ?

Comment: Again, where is the call to the `.validate()` method?  The plugin is not initialized on the form without it.

Comment: ok... look again.. please ;)

Comment: You seemed really desperate for a solution so I did my best for you... the least you could do is respond to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a rough idea about how you are supposed to declare multiple rules.  I cannot make any further sense out of your question, so you'll need to adjust this accordingly.

```
$("#Form").validate({
    rules: {
        id_level: "required",     // <- shortcut for one rule
        job: {                    // <- more than one rule on this field
            required: true,  
            notEqual: '#id_level' // <- set your custom rule parameter to id="id_level"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        id_level: "choose one",
        job: {
            required: "must fill" // <- need to specify which rule here
        }
    }
});
```

You'll also need to tweak your custom method a bit, so that you can obtain the `value` of the field you're passing in using the `param`.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value != $(param).val();
}, "Please specify a different value");
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ztjz4/**