# Jquery Validation for confirm serial

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code in Jquery for confirmation of not re-entering same Serial

Rule that needs to be follow is:
1. Required filled(done)
2.minLength 5 (done)
3.cant input same serial if serial is already inputted in other textbox(missing validation)

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
     while (serialGeneratedQuantity < 10) {
           serialGeneratedQuantity++;
           serial+serialGeneratedQuantity: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
            },
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to create a validation for same serial input to validate and prompt a error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571347/how-to-add-a-not-equal-to-rule-in-jquery-validation Hope this will help you.