# how to add NOTEqual To rule in jQuery.validation

Tags: c#, jquery, validation

I want to know how i can add jquery validation for not equal values in two input textbox. I have tried this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571347/how-to-add-a-not-equal-to-rule-in-jquery-validation) but its not working for me.

Jquery Code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
            return this.optional(element) || value != param;
        }, "cannot be same as oldpassword");

        $("#frmAddEdit").validate({
            rules: {
                "txtoldpassword": { required: true },
                "txtnpassword": { required: true, notEqual:"#txtoldpassword" },
            },
            messages: {
                "txtoldpassword": { required: "old Password is required" },
                "txtnpassword": { required: "New Password is required" },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                ChangeUserPassword();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

When i put alert on validation method param shows the same value (i.e. `#txtoldpassword`) and when i put like this `notEqual: $("#txtoldpassword").val()`  param becomes `""`(blank)

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the way of passing value of textbox for notEqual and it worked for me.

JQuery Code :

```
  $("#frmAddEdit").validate({
            rules: {
                "txtoldpassword": { required: true, noSpace: true },
                "txtnpassword": {
                    required: true, noSpace: true, notEqual: function () { return $("#txtoldpassword").val() },
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "txtoldpassword": { required: "old Password is required" },
                "txtnpassword": { required: "New Password is required" },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                ChangeUserPassword();
                return false;
            }
        });
```